# No overflow on background with transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got the following http://jsfiddle.net/9dy38529/7/ code.

It all boils down in this HTML:

```
<div class="view view-third">
 <div class="pre-mask"><h1>Lorem</h1></div>
 <img src="http://goo.gl/Dr6upR" />
 <div class="mask">
  <h2>Lorem</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum solar mit</p>
  <a href="#" class="info">Lorem</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem:
**After hovering it shows the background color without using the `overflow-hidden` then after the transition it is correct again.**

I believe I followed all the rules but this is getting me confused. I already tried a lot of other SO suggestions like adding an extra `position:relative;` by creating a div as parent from .pre-mask but this did not work. Also I have had `overflow-hidden` on nearly every class in the code. Which didn't work either. Then I tried to hide it with a transition but this messed the existing traditions up. So I am bit lost.

Comment: Side note:  `ransition-delay: 0.3s;` i think this needs to be  `transition-delay: 0.3s;` on your sqlfiddle example?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you so much for pointing that out. Saved me another headbanging session. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a `z-index` issue. Apply a `z-index` to the `.view` like:  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dy38529/9/)

```
.view {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    /*-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;*/
    cursor: default;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    z-index:99999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is it. I am really curious how you knew that. I have been banging my head for two hours now.

Comment: I didn't actually know that would work. More of a hunch. I wish I had a better explanation :(

Comment: I am glad with your hunch. It saved me. Next time I try the z-index first. Never even came into my mind. Thanks again.